# Perl framework for datatype checking

Tags: perl, validation, types

So I'd like to bring a bit of Mouse speed to my other subroutines and do a bit of type checking à la

```
sub mysub {
    my ($self, $int) = @_;
    assert_int($int, 'int[1]');
}
```

The subroutine arguments is the data to assert & an optional name for this data. This is so we get a more useful error message e.g.

```
Assertion error! 'int[1]' is not an integer; got 'HASH(0xXXXXXXXXX)'
```

Writing it in pure Perl was not hard. When you compare it to the speed in Mouse & gfx's other module Data::Util, ~4x faster than pure Perl, it's obvious that pure XS solutions have the upper-hand but they lack this optional parameter name. Writing a small wrapper around Data::Util's check functions are still way slower than using XS directly.

Does anyone know of a suite of fast data type assertion utilities which allow for this field name to be passed into the assertion?

**EDIT** after @ikegami answer on how to use Mouse's type system it seems that the performance is still lacking in comparison to just using XS libraries. So the question morphs more into *Is there an XS based framework which can provide customisable error messages or at least lets you say what the attribute is called*.

**EDIT** this is the code I'm currently comparing the performance against. This has been massively based on gfx's work on `Data::Util` and `Mouse`'s XS mode. This gives us 5x the speed on a pure Perl solution. It is somewhat unfair to compare C to Perl which is why I was wondering if a framework already exists which can give this performance but with the right kind of error message. I don't want to be writing this stuff if someone else has already done it :)

```
use Inline C => <<'END_C';

static int S_nv_is_integer(pTHX_ NV const nv) {
  if(nv == (NV)(IV)nv){
    return TRUE;
  }
  else {
    char buf[64];  /* Must fit sprintf/Gconvert of longest NV */
    const char* p;
    (void)Gconvert(nv, NV_DIG, 0, buf);
    p = &buf[0];

    /* -?[0-9]+ */
    if(*p == '-') p++;

    while(*p){
        if(!isDIGIT(*p)){
            return FALSE;
        }
        p++;
    }
    return TRUE;
  }
}

int assert_int(SV* sv, char* attributeName) {
  assert(sv);
  int result;
  if(SvPOKp(sv)){
    int const num_type = grok_number(SvPVX(sv), SvCUR(sv), NULL);
    result = num_type && !(num_type & IS_NUMBER_NOT_INT);
  }
  else if(SvIOKp(sv)){
    result = TRUE;
  }
  else if(SvNOKp(sv)) {
    result = S_nv_is_integer(aTHX_ SvNVX(sv));
  }
  else {
    result = FALSE;
  }

  if(! result) {
    croak("'%s' was not an integer; got '%s'", attributeName, SvPV(sv, PL_na));
  }
  return result;
}

END_C
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want what Mouse uses, nothing's stopping you.

```
my $int_constraint = Mouse::Util::TypeConstraints::find_type_constraint('Int');

sub mysub {
    my ($self, $int) = @_;
    $int_constraint->assert_valid($int);
    ...
}
```

If you use `check or die` instead of `assert_valid` if you want to provide your own message.

I've used this with Moose, but it looks like it should work with Mouse too.

Comment: Thanks for the information about how to access the Mouse type constraints I didn't see that method in the documentation at all. Feel quite silly now :). I've rerun my benchmarks using Mouse and the performance of it looks to be lower than the regular Perl version. So the question does slightly change now to does a XS based framework allow for error message customisation without a huge penalty.

Comment: @andeyatz, Perhaps you aren't looking at the wrong class? The constraint is a Mouse::Meta::Constraint

Comment: @andeyatz, I'm confused, you said Mouse was fast enough. What changed?

Comment: When Mouse is used directly it is very fast indeed (or at least the overall XS based framework is fast) but using the constraints directly seems to be very slow.